# Loop through a range of cells in a worksheet and copy and paste to new sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have no experience I VBA but have been given the task to create a list of transferring a bin location from an old to new

I need to take the data in my worksheet "S005" copy each cell then paste that data into a work sheet called "mapping 005"
Each row in "S005" has a Serial number "S/N" and the "mapping 005" work sheet 
has a corresponding serial number.
The data from S005 has to be put in the correct place in mapping 005

S/N     Typ     Sec StorageBin  New Bin Material    Stock   Weight

1   001 005 A09-01-40   R06-07-70   117-7029 1       0.768

but how do I make this loop through all the rows

```
Sub CopyDATA1()

Set ws1 = Worksheets("S005")
Set ws4 = Worksheets("Mapping 005")

With ws4
    .Range("c3").Value = ws1.Range("b2").Value
    .Range("c4").Value = ws1.Range("c2").Value
    .Range("c5").Value = ws1.Range("d2").Value
    .Range("c6").Value = ws1.Range("e2").Value
    .Range("c7").Value = ws1.Range("f2").Value
    .Range("c8").Value = ws1.Range("g2").Value
    .Range("c9").Value = ws1.Range("h2").Value
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: You should attempt to write some code, then post it in the question to try and get help

Answer (score 0):

No need of Loop here... :)

```
Sub CopyDATA1()
Dim wCopy As Worksheet, wPaste As Worksheet, lRw As Long

Set wCopy = Worksheets("S005")
Set wPaste = Worksheets("Mapping 005")

With wCopy
    lRw = Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
    .Range("C3:C" & lRw).Copy
    wPaste.Range("B2").PasteSpecial Transpose:=True
End With

Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```